# Azure Logic Apps get skipped when running

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Good day! I am trying to build an Azure Logic Apps Consumption Type workflow, From Sharepoint we will get the data in rows and will ingest it to SQL Server. The workflow ran successfully but it is giving 202 Status messages and the trigger history is Skipped. Can you please advise what is wrong with our design?

Please see the screenshot of the design and the output below. Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

I tried to check the connection for SharePoint, Excel and SQL server and it was connected properly. I would like to know if there's any other blocker as to why it was skipper or not running.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So have you change the properties of a file? What about triggers conditions?

Comment: Hello @Skin, I haven't change any property of a file. The trigger condition is the first one "When a file is created or modified (properties only)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The workflow ran successfully but it is giving 202 Status messages and the trigger history is Skipped.
> Azure Logic Apps get skipped when running

You should not manually run the logic app, when you run these skipped will occur.
This is normal behavior as you have set time trigger is checking for any updates, because they are no updates the trigger is getting skipped like below and it is even same to me:

But whenever there is a change it provides you with succeeded as below:

[image]

But when you check run history it will give you only when changes made or new file added as below:

[image]

[image]

My design:

[image]

You need not run it manually, but when there is some changes or new file is added in the folder then this will trigger.

Comment: Hi @RithwikBojja Thank you for this helpful answer, I updated the file and it didn't skipped, but I do have a current problem and hope you can help me. 

Please see the screenshot: